# How to move a plane with touch using SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have made a plane using SceneKit and I want to move this plane with touch from one position to another point. How can I move this plane?

```
    //code for plane
    let planeGeo = SCNPlane(width: 15, height: 15)
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeo)
    planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y:-5, z:-5)
    planeNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(x: Float(-M_PI/2), y:0, z: 0)
    planeNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.staticBody()
    let planeMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    planeMaterial.diffuse.contents = "texture.png"
    planeGeo.materials = [planeMaterial]
```

Answer (score 0):

See SCNAction, specifically the .moveTo() and .moveBy() functions.

Comment: using moveTo() or moveBY() it will automatic move but i not want that in my case i want it should move with user touch gestures or with mouse touch...

Comment: Trigger the action based on a user touch.